# Why did Winter Bash 2015 go down?

Tags: bug, winter-bash-2015

It appears that Winter Bash just went down.  [The Winter Bash site](http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com) now redirects to http://stack exchange.com/promos.  Additionally, the snowflake and my hats have disappeared from my view.  Is this a bug?

Comment: Are you using FF? Because I had to [clear the cache for that page](http://superuser.com/questions/173210/how-can-i-clear-a-single-site-from-the-cache-in-firefox) to make it stop auto-redirecting to the promos page.

Comment: Ugh.  Well, this question turns out to be a duplicate because I was using the ios app to post it, which slowed me down and allowed someone else to beat me to the punch.  Too bad, I might have gotten the "Amazing Grace" hat.

Comment: Hmmm.  I wonder if this would give me waffles.

Comment: Or this? ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Or maybe.... this!!!!